# How to configure LDAP for pgadmin.whl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, pgadmin

Configured according to the instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode-ru
When setting up **pgadmin.whl** I use **python3.6**
In **config_local.py** added:

```
LOG_FILE = '/var/log/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.log'
SQLITE_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db'
SESSION_DB_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
STORAGE_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage'
SERVER_MODE = True
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['ldap', 'internal']
LDAP_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
LDAP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
LDAP_SERVER_URI =  'ldaps://myldapsserver:636'
LDAP_BASE_DN =  'ou=users,dc=mydc,dc=ru'
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = 'uid'
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = 'uid={0}'
```

When trying **LDAP** authorization, I get an error:

```
2020-05-20 14:29:09,990: ERROR  flask.app:      Error binding to the LDAP server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/authenticate/ldap.py", line 115, in connect
    auto_bind=True
  File "/home/administrator/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 355, in __init__
    self.do_auto_bind()
  File "/home/administrator/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 384, in do_auto_bind
    raise LDAPBindError(self.last_error)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: None
```

Please tell me how it can be fixed?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. I think in my case anonymous bind to LDAP is rejected but I cannot find documentation on how to set the bind user and password in the config. It's also not clear if a private cert is really required for LDAPS or optional (generated automatically)

Comment: I've just found this as well: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFOhELdVb6mwStX-9EET-KL30AizVr6G1=FRF5w92+78=0p6Yw@mail.gmail.com
I'm not sure if they've indicated here that the logon user is used for the bind or if no auth is done for the bind at all. Either way, it looks like they've accepted a proposal for independent bind user configuration for an upcoming release.

Comment: Can you tell me where/how you were able to see that log data that shows LDAP errors? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I follow https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/enabling_ldap_authentication.html and it is working for me, with theses parameters :

```
[root@pg ~]# cat /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/config_distro.py
HELP_PATH = '/usr/share/doc/pgadmin4-docs/en_US/html'
UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED = False
LOG_FILE = '/var/log/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.log'
SQLITE_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db'
SESSION_DB_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
STORAGE_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage'
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['ldap', 'internal']
LDAP_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldaps://idm.mydomain.org:636'
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = 'uid'
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=org'
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = '(&(objectclass=inetUser)(|(memberOf=cn=developpeurs,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=org)))'
LDAP_USE_STARTTLS = True
LDAP_CA_CERT_FILE = '/etc/ipa/ca.crt'
LDAP_CERT_FILE = '/etc/pki/tls/certs/http.mydomain.org.crt'
LDAP_KEY_FILE = '/etc/pki/tls/private/http.mydomain.org.key'
```

And the filter is on the group "developpeurs".
After, You can find ldap users into "User Management" into pgadmin4 automatically.